# Blender model export (in .dae) to THREE.JS not showing probably

Tags: javascript, model, 3d, three.js, blender

I generated a "cloud" in blender using the "cloud generator add-on", then exported it in ".dae" format to three.js:

```
var modelname="cloud_0";

var object1 = new PinaCollada('cloud_0', 100);
scene.add(object1); 
var object2 = new PinaCollada('cloud_0', 100);
scene.add(object2);

function PinaCollada(modelname, scale) 
{

var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var localObject;
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load( 'models/'+modelname+'.dae', function colladaReady( collada ) {
    localObject = collada.scene;
    localObject.scale.x = localObject.scale.y = localObject.scale.z = scale;
    localObject.updateMatrix();
} );
return localObject;
}
```

I can successfully see objects being imported; but the faces of the clouds appear as geometrical blank shapes that has nothing to do with the original objects.

How to overcome this?

Update: I included a screenshot for the three.js scene and the original blender  scene:

-blender:
[image]

-three.js:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search and questions, I found at that simulations and effects (like smoke and clouds) are not exportable,so it's a blender issue rather than a three.js issue; see here:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90057/exported-model-done-with-cloud-generator-a-o-not-showing-probably?noredirect=1#comment158671_90057